# MVP with ViewModel component

Tags: android, android-mvp

**Disclaimer: This is not a MVP vs MVVM post.**

I've made a simple project to see how MVP works

**My Activity**:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MainContract.View {

    lateinit var presenter: MainPresenter
    private val counter by lazy { findViewById<TextView>(R.id.value_tv) }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        presenter = MainPresenter(this)

        increment_value_btn.setOnClickListener {
            presenter.incrementCount()
        }

        decrement_value_btn.setOnClickListener {
            presenter.decrementCount()
        }

    }

    override fun updateCount(count: Int) {
        counter.text = count.toString()
    }
}
```

**My Presenter**:

```
class MainPresenter(mainView: View) : Presenter {

    var view: View = mainView
    var counter: Int = 0

    override fun incrementCount() {
        counter++
        view.updateCount(counter)
    }

    override fun decrementCount() {
        counter--
        view.updateCount(counter)
    }

}
```

When configurations changes (orientation) my number is reset. I know it's a normal behaviour as the activity is dropped and re-created. I've read that [viewmodel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) is designed to help the data survives. However I don't know how to implement it with my presenter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I reworked my application and decided to go directly with MVVM and followed [this course](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-view-model/#0)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following approach

First create a base presenter interface as below

```
interface BasePresenter<View : BaseView> : LifecycleObserver {
        var view: View?
        var viewLifecycle: Lifecycle?

        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
        fun attachView(view: View, viewLifecycle: Lifecycle?) {
            this.view = view
            this.viewLifecycle = viewLifecycle
            viewLifecycle?.addObserver(this)
        }

        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
        override fun onViewDestroyed() {
         view = null
         viewLifecycle = null
        }
 }
```

Then optionally you can create a base view interface with the basic operations

```
  interface BaseView {
    fun showProgressDialog()
    fun hideProgressDialog()
 }
```

And your presenter class should looks like

```
class MainPresenter() : BasePresenter<MainView> {

    var counter: Int = 0

    override fun incrementCount() {
        counter++
        view?.updateCount(counter)
    }

    override fun decrementCount() {
        counter--
        view?.updateCount(counter)
    }

}
```

And then wherever you initialize your presenter instance don't forget to attach the view implementation as below

```
presenter.attachView(this, lifecycle)
```

**Explanation of this implementation**

Presenter extending ViewModel might seem weird, but let’s not confuse it with ViewModel
 from MVVM - ViewModel in AC is “designed to store and manage UI-related data in a lifecycle conscious way”,
 which is exactly what we want to achieve

By extending ViewModel the Presenter instance will survive configuration changes

By passing and observing viewLifecycle every Presenter will automatically set it’s view reference to null before the view gets destroyed

[Article explaining in detail](https://proandroiddev.com/lifecycle-aware-presenter-instead-of-livedata-f77d640115ef)

Comment: I think there is a typo in your `attachView` you put `Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY` wouldn't it be `Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE` ?
Does that also means I have to call `onViewDestroyed()` when the view goes in `onDestroy()` ? I didn't understand why not use ViewModel in AC if it's exactly what we want. I also intend to use DI later, will that change anything in how to set `presenter` ?

Comment: @Biscuit yes i have edited the answer, sorry for the typo.

Comment: There won't be a problem if you use DI to create an instance of your presenter.  As i mention in the answer you should attach the view and the lifecycle of your activity or fragment using the attachView method

Comment: No, you don't have to call `onViewDestroyed`  in `OnDestroy` because thanks to passing and observing viewLifecycle every Presenter will automatically set it’s view reference to null before the view gets destroyed

Comment: Okay! I also found this cool [article](https://proandroiddev.com/attach-your-presenters-to-view-layer-40263ed425fb)

Comment: I tried what you said and it's not working. Next time quote your [source](https://proandroiddev.com/lifecycle-aware-presenter-instead-of-livedata-f77d640115ef)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209185/discussion-between-oscar-emilio-perez-martinez-and-biscuit).